# A hard true or false question. "$M$ is measurable iff. for any subset $E\subseteq M$ we have $|M|_e=|E|_e+|M-E|_e$"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can we say $M$ is Lebesgue measurable iff for any subset $E\subseteq M$ we have  $|M|_e=|E|_e+|M-E|_e$? Here $|M|_e$ denotes outer measure.

My feeling is that it cannot be right, or this is a very intuitive statement that should appear as a theorem, not exercise. But I have tried for one day and could not figure it out.

I think the sufficiency has something to do with non-measurable set, because if $E$ is measurable the sufficiency holds. And there is a theorem saying that every set with a positive outer measure has a non-measurable subset.

I have no clue on the necessity at this moment. Hope someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: How do you define measurability?

Comment: Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: I understand, but different authors have different definitions; equivalent, but different.

Comment: How does your book/class define Lebesgue measurability?

Comment: The definition can be $M$ is measurable iff. for any set $A\subseteq \Bbb{R}$ $|M\bigcap A|_e+|M^C \bigcap A|_e=|A|_e$, or $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists an open set $M \subseteq G$ st. $|G-M|_e<\epsilon$. These are two definitions on my textbook.

Comment: This statement in question looks like the first definition. I am trying to see if it contradicts with that one, but has no luck so far.

Answer (score 3):

There are measurable sets for which the given condition fails:

Let $E$ be any non-measurable set of finite measure $|E|_e \in (0,\infty)$. It follows (for example using the definition of the outer measure) that there is a measurable set $M$ (even a $G_\delta$ set) with $E \subset M$ and $|M| = |E|_e$. But we do **not** have

$$
|M|_e = |E|_e + |M - E|_e,
$$
since this would imply $|M - E|_e = 0$, so that $M - E$ is measurable (as a null-set). But then so is $M - (M - E) = E$, a contradiction.

This disproves one of the two implications (and thus also the equivalence).

---

At the moment, I am not sure about the other implication (i.e. does the given condition imply measurability?). If I come up with something, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Wow... I was so close... I should think about $G_\delta$. This is a good one!